# Can I implement automatic call to someone in Android?

Tags: android

I want to implement an automatic call from my android phone. If I set message for a particular number and date as well, then my android phone should call that number automatically. Is it possible without any user interaction to call on any number via my android phone?

Comment: Yes @Me and We right. You should try with his way of method. Use the `AlarmManager` for this. And, use the `Intent.ACTION_CALL`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is possible. The code for call is straight forward.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);   
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:09999"));    
startActivity(intent);
```

Use your number in place of `09999`.
Don't forget to specify the permission to call in Android Manifest.xml

Comment: that means with the help of alarm manager and above CALL_ACTION i can make call to stored number without any interaction. right?

Comment: Exactly! You can use a timer task too.

Answer (score 3):

Create an `Alarm` that will be fired at a particular time and add the code to call any particular number. [**Here**](http://justcallmebrian.com/?p=129) is how you can set the `AlarmManager` to fire at a particular time. Then you can just call `Intent.ACTION_CALL` when your Alarm is fired.

Comment: that means with the help of alarm manager and using above API i can make call to stored number without any interaction. right?

Comment: yes you can just call the code for calling at the particular alarm time and make a call.

Comment: _Is it possible without any user interaction to call on any number via my android phone_ Is it possible without root ???

Comment: @SweetWisherツ not sure but you can try it for sure!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, with [Intent.ACTION_CALL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CALL).