# how to add a dial number and press the `call` bottom?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-alertdialog

I want to trigger an intent that opens the dialer adds a number and then

presses the  `call` bottom.

Is there any way to do the `press` bottom ?

```
private void SendDialIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone.phone));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can i implement automatic call to someone in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378866/can-i-implement-automatic-call-to-someone-in-android). It looks like you could just change `DIAL` to `CALL`.

Comment: then what is `ACTION_CALL_BOTTON`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "press the call button". You can use `ACTION_CALL` (instead of `ACTION_DIAL`), which will directly place the phone call. This requires the `CALL_PHONE` permission and will not work for emergency numbers (e.g., 911 in the US).

Comment: then what is `ACTION_CALL_BOTTON`?

Comment: Without ANY permissions you can dial the number (fill in the dialer with your number) and not actually start the call.  You should do this (it is much nicer to your user).

Comment: @user1065869: For devices that have an off-screen call button, pressing that button triggers an activity that supports `ACTION_CALL_BUTTON`. It is not an `Intent` action that you use yourself to start other activities, and very few devices have off-screen call buttons nowadays.