# How Do I Make My App Automatically Call Someone?

Tags: java, android

I've been fiddling with an emergency-esque contact app for a while now and I'm close to being done. After a timer runs out, the app should call a number that the user has saved previously.

I've come awful close to making it dial the number automatically, however I can only seem to make it take the number and put it in the dialer without calling the number.

I really want this to be automatic, how do I make the number get called automatically?

```
(timer finishes)
String myCallNumber ="tel:" + myPref.getString("phoneINT", "");
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(myCallNumber)));
```

I tried this code, from linked duplicate. However, it says that Call_Action isn't a real thing.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.CALL_ACTION);   
intent.setData(Uri.parse(myCallNumber));    
startActivity(intent);
```

This question is **not** a duplicate of [Can I implement automatic call to someone in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378866/can-i-implement-automatic-call-to-someone-in-android) !

Intent.CALL_ACTION does not work for me, Android studios doesn't recognize it as a command.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vixo.png)

Comment: A duplicate of what dude

Comment: Link's at the top.

Comment: The link provided does not remedy the problem.

Comment: Please unmark my question as a duplicate

Comment: How is your question different?

Comment: Well I tried the solution they posted and it didn't work. I'm using a countdown timer, and they're using an alarmManager. Additionally, the solution they posted uses CALL_ACTION, which doesn't work for API 22

Comment: You'll need to be more specific than "it doesn't work". Did you read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CALL)? Did you request the right [permissions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CALL_PHONE)?

Comment: Call_Action cannot be resolved. Listen man, can ya not screw my question over here? I'm new and I'm trying to figure stuff out, so I don't understand everything yet. I'd really appreciate it if ya didn't hide my question here.

Comment: Theres nothing that says my Permissions aren't good. Android Studio adds the stuff anyways now with the newest update.

Comment: It's `ACTION_CALL`, not `CALL_ACTION`.