# Cannot Dial Phone Number Automatically After Timer Ends

Tags: java, android

I've been fiddling with an emergency-esque contact app for a while now and I'm close to being done. After a timer runs out, the app should call a number that the user has saved previously.

I've come awful close to making it dial the number automatically, however I can only seem to make it take the number and put it in the dialer without calling the number.

I really want this to be automatic, how do I make the number get called automatically?

```
(timer finishes)
String myCallNumber ="tel:" + myPref.getString("phoneINT", "");
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(myCallNumber)));
```

Nothing says that I need any additional permissions. Actually, I took this from a webpage tutorial that said no permissions were required.

I tried this code, from linked duplicate. However, it says that Call_Action isn't a real thing.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.CALL_ACTION);   
intent.setData(Uri.parse(myCallNumber));    
startActivity(intent);
```

This question is **not** a duplicate of [Can I implement automatic call to someone in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378866/can-i-implement-automatic-call-to-someone-in-android) !

Intent.CALL_ACTION does not work for me, Android studios doesn't recognize it as a command.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vixo.png)

Comment: [ACTION_CALL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CALL) - it says that Call_Action isn't a real thing, maybe it is correct

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi please check if you already granted permission. Also, it should be "ACTION_CALL", not "CALL_ACTION"

1. add into AndroidManifest.xml:

   uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"
2. Check permission before calling:

   ```
   int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
                                            Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);

   if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
       ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
               this,
               new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
               999);
   } else {
       startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL).setData(Uri.parse("tel: your_phone_number")));
   }

   @Override
   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
       switch (requestCode) {

           case 999:
               if ((grantResults.length > 0) && (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                   startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL).setData(Uri.parse("tel:your_phone_number")));
               } 
               break;

           default:
               break;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, but I just discovered the answer to fix the problem. If you post this as your answer, I'll mark it as correct since thats what worked for me.

Comment: yes, it is my answer, it is a common pattern when you want to do an action which requires dangerous permissions.

Comment: So I'm really new, so why is it a dangerous permission?

Comment: In order to protect end users, Google ask developers to declare what they intend to do if it may harm them. There are two types of this: normal one: you just need to declare on Android Manifest so that end users will notice when they download the app. The second one is dangerous which you need to ask for permission from end users to use. It is categorized by Google, if they think an action is dangerous, it is dangerous. Please refer this for more information: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview.html